Why is my CSS stylesheet not linking well with my html document?
I don't know why the HTML document doesn't update with the CSS properties
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<title>Quen Somos?</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href="./quen-somos.css">
<link rel="icon"  type="image/x-icon" href="../IMAXES/Estrela.png">
<meta name="keywords" content="Erguer, Galiza, organización estudantil, ANC, 2016, sindicato de estudantes">
<meta charset="Utf-8">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
     <div id="second-row">
         <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCcr33NXAArfvqIwW4C_AdXg"><img src="../IMAXES/Youtube.png" alt="Icona de Youtube" width="15px"></a>
         <a href="https://www.instagram.com/erguergaliza/?hl=en"><img src="../IMAXES/Instagram.jpg" alt="Icona de Instagram" width="15px"></a>
         <a href="https://www.facebook.com/erguergaliza/?locale=es_ES"><img src="../IMAXES/Facebook.jpg" alt="Icona de Facebook" width="15px"></a>
         <a href="https://twitter.com/erguergaliza?lang=en"><img src="../IMAXES/Twitter.png" alt="Icona de Twitter" width="15px"></a>
        </div>
     <div id="second-row">
         <img src="../IMAXES/Erguer.png" alt="Símbolo de Erguer">
         <a href="#" id="limpa">Membros de Erguer</a>
     </div>
     
</header>
<main>
</main>
</body>
</html>

I have already checked the relative URL path, and it's correct, so I don't know where the problem is
I did whatever I could, and, in fact, when i inspect the document, the css document appears as a source
<!-- Estilos do header-->
body
{
    margin:0px;
}
header
{
    width:100%;
}
    <!--Primeira parte-->
                #first-row
                {     
                    background-color:red;
                    float:right;
                    padding:10px 30px 10px 0px;
                }
        
    <!--Segunda Parte-->
                #second-row
                {   
                    background-color:white;
                    float:left;
                }
                #limpa
                {
                    clear:left;
                    background-color:inherit;
                    margin:30px;
                    font-family:Algerian, "Times New Roman", Arial;
                    text-decoration:none;
                    color:black;
                }
                
    <!--Terceira e última parte-->


You have invalid markup in your CSS file. Comments in CSS are /* */, not <!-- -->. The CSS applies just fine once you fix that error.

What do the console and network tabs in your dev tools show you? I'm inclined to vote to close this as due to a typo as TylerH pointed out

Most probably it is your invalid markup. Check your console

I rolled back your recent edits as they invalidated the existing answer. If you still have a problem after fixing the issue as shown, then ask a new question, and provide a [mre].

The issue seems to be with the structure of your CSS comments. In CSS, comments should be written using /* */, not HTML-style comments .
